# Should all validation rules be tested within a Cucumber feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

In Ruby on Rails, if all of the validation rules for a given model are being tested within that model's spec (or unit tests), is it still considered necessary to write a Cucumber scenario for each validation?

Would it suffice to instead write two scenarios: One for when valid data is entered, and one for when invalid data is entered?

Comment: I apologise if this is a silly question - I'm still trying to wrap my head around BDD.

Comment: I share your point of view: two cucumber scenario are enough in your case.

Comment: @apneadiving: But consider the situation if you were building a wholesale e-commerce site, where a customer must order at least 10 units of each item. That validation is an important business rule, and should be exposed at the Cucumber level.

Comment: @andy: you're definitely right, the case you present needs integration testing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a good question, and the answer is: It depends.

You can think of Cucumber as a way of communicating between the product owner, developers and testers.

If you feel that having the validations in Cucumber adds to the shared understanding of what the product does, then keep them there.

One approach is to combine the validations into a scenario outline:

```
Scenario Outline: User tries to register but skips a mandatory field
  Given I am registering
  And I leave the "<field>" blank 
  When I click "Submit"
  Then I should see "<message>"
  And I should not be registered
    | field         | message                         |
    | Forename      | Please enter your forename      |
    | Surname       | Please enter your surname       |
    | Date of Birth | Please enter your date of birth |
```

Comment: This seems like a nice compromise. But what about different types of validations (uniqueness, length, etc.) Would I need a different scenario outline for each type?

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing the context. Could you give an example?

Comment: How about a User model where the username must be unique and contain only alphanumeric characters, the password must be at least 6 characters long, and the email address must be valid. My thinking is that since the validations are already being tested in the model spec, it should be sufficient to simply test the two possible outcomes in the controller's create action within the Cucumber features - namely, when the model saves successfully and when it doesn't.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm completely missing the point of Cucumber - that's possible too :P

Comment: Ok, let's take the password example. Does your product owner care if the minimum length is 5 characters or 6 characters? I would suspect not. To him, the important thing is that is not easily guessable or hackable. The decision on the minimum password length should probably be made by the programmer, as he will have the knowledge and experience to pick a suitable minimum length. So the minimum password length should probably not be exposed in a Cucumber feature.

Comment: @Andy Waite: That's a very good point. Looks like most of the validations should stay in the model spec then. Thanks very much for your input.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question, and one that I have been dealing with recently.

It may be different for your organization, but in my organization we try to leave the field validation tests to the unit tests or some other framework that handles these situations better. Aside from that, I am of the school of thought that Cucumber is meant purely for automated acceptance testing (AKA a communications tool between you/your team and the PO) -- and that other methods should be used for anything outside that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Why leave anything open to suggestion? Allowing for assumptions made by developers is inherently risky in terms of generating rework.

How each field a form **behaves** under different circumstances (create, display, edit, persona) is clearly acceptance criteria.

If you hide it away in a unit test then you are disconnecting it from the *living documentation*

You really shouldn't need unit tests if you are really bought into the BDD way.

```
Feature: Edit staff personal
  Scenario Outline: Form validation
    Given I am editing a staff personal details
    And the form contains a "<Mandatory?>" field with a label "<Label>"
    And text fields have a input length of between "<Min Length>" and "<Max Length>"
    And select fields have these "<Options>"
    When I submit the form by clicking the save button
    Then an error displays if validation fails
    But commits my changes if validation is successful and returns the form back to display mode
    Examples:
    | Label | Mandatory? | Type | Min length | Max length | Options
    | Title | true | select | 0 | 0 | Mr, Mrs, Miss, Ms, Dr, Prof |
    | Surname | true | text | 2 | 50 | null |
    | Forename | true | text | 2 | 50 | null |
    | Known as / Other Surname | false | text | 2 | 50 | null |
    | Known as forename | false | text | 2 | 50 | null |
    | Date of birth | true | date-picker | 0 | 0 | null |
    | NI number | true | ni-number | 0 | 0 | null |
```